# iTunes synching of played podcast episodes between OS X and Windows 7

Tags: macos, itunes, data-synchronization, windows, podcasts

I've got iTunes (always latest version so currently 12.2) installed on both, my Mac at home and my work PC running Windows 7.

Having both iTunes apps synched to the same account was always a great to keep track of what episodes of the many podcasts I'm subscribed to I've already listened to.

However, since a couple of versions it's completely broken.

Despite the "**Sync playback information**" and "**Sync podcast subscriptions**" being checked on both machines the information about played podcasts will not sync anymore.

Is this a known issue?  Does anybody know of a workaround?

Going through dozens of episodes each week on both machines and marking them as played is just annoying and a waste of time.. despite the fact that the list of unplayed podcasts is always a mess on either machine.